# What else i can use instead of class for Jquery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For buttons i am using class for assigning css classes. But i have to define a selector for those. I know i can use class for jquery selector but what else i can use and how ?

They are rendered as input not buttons.

```
<asp:Button ID="imgBtnTurkish" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" class="DefaultTitle" title="Turkish Spoken Chat Section" runat="server" OnClick="btnTurkishChat_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
```

Comment: they are rendered as input not buttons.    <asp:Button ID="imgBtnTurkish" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';"  class="DefaultTitle" title="Turkish Spoken Chat Section"
                    runat="server" OnClick="btnTurkishChat_Click" CausesValidation="False" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that you could choose from. One possibility to select the button is to wrap it in a div element with a given class:

```
<div class="DefaultTitle">
    <asp:Button 
        ID="imgBtnTurkish" 
        onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" 
        title="Turkish Spoken Chat Section" 
        runat="server" 
        OnClick="btnTurkishChat_Click" 
        CausesValidation="False" 
    />
</div>
```

and then use the following selector: `$('.DefaultTitle input')`.

Comment: i already find that but did you understand what i mean ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG, I thought you were looking for some other way of selecting your buttons instead of class selectors. Apparently I was wrong. So what do you mean?

Comment: yes and you didnt tell me any way to do it. i am already looking that page and cant find. if i were able to i wouldnt ask it here. and buttons are rendered as inputs at output.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG, you didn't show how your markup looks like and what do you want to select. There are hundreds of ways of showing *buttons* in HTML. If they are input fields with `type="submit"` you could select them like this `$(':submit')`. Or you could wrap them in some `<div class="someClass">...your button here...</div>` and then `$('.someClass :submit');`.

Comment: i want to select specific inputs not all of them. class is letting me do that by defining but since i cant use class tag i need something else.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG, you could wrap those inputs into some container DOM elements and then use the class selector I showed.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. i am not good with jquery. i am using ready tooltip TipTip plugin.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG, you wrap your button into a div with a class: `<div class="myButton"><asp:Button ID="imgBtnTurkish" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" class="DefaultTitle" title="Turkish Spoken Chat Section" runat="server" OnClick="btnTurkishChat_Click" CausesValidation="False" /></div>` and then `$('.myButton input')` to select it.

Comment: yes finally solved my problem thank you. if you edit first post i will also give you vote up.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG, I have updated my post to include this example.

Answer (score 1):

Selects all kind of buttons:

```
$('button, input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset]')
```

If you want a **specific** element, you need to **specify** it with some attribute!

It could be the class `$('.myClass')`, the ID `$('#myId')` or any other attribute `$('input[title=myAwesomeTitle]')`.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: so you say that there is no other way than id or class ?

Comment: You can search for every single attribute on that element. like `input[name=myname]` or `input[title=myAwesomeTitle]`!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign both a class and an id to an HTML element, then use the class for CSS and the id for selecting. This is the method I prefer to use personally.

in markup:

```
<input type="button" class="myButtonCssClass" id="myButton1" value="click me!" />
```

in javascript:

```
$('#myButton1').click(function () { // do something awesome! });
```

Comment: they already have unique ids. this way i would have to define over 30  $('#myButton1').click(function () { // do something awesome! });
  so not feasible